# Modal with List of items

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am using angular 5 and spring Boot. I have a list of items that i want to show their details via modals. That means if i click on any item the modal contains that item details. 
Has any one any idea about how to implement that?

this is my list :

```
   <mat-card>
      <mat-card-content>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" style="width: 110px;" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="motCle" aria-label="Search">
          <button  (click)="chercher()"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </div>
        <mat-list>
          <mat-list-item style="color: black;" *ngFor="let p of pans">
            <h3 mat-line >{{p.id}}- {{p.nom}}</h3>
            <span class="clickable" style="color: #cccccc;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open clickable"></span>
          </mat-list-item>
          <div style="float: left" class="container">
            <ul  style="background-color: transparent;" class="nav nav-pills">
              <li  [ngClass]="{'active':i==currentpage}" *ngFor="let p of pages; let i=index">
                <a style="color: #cccccc;" class="clickable" (click)="gotoPage(i)">{{i}}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </mat-list>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

with material dialog : https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

html

```
<mat-list-item style="color: black;" *ngFor="let p of pans">
            <h3 mat-line >{{p.id}}- {{p.nom}}</h3>
            <span (click)="openDetail(p)" class="clickable" style="color: #cccccc;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open clickable"></span>
          </mat-list-item>
```

ts

```
openDetail(pan) {
   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(yourDialogComponent, {
      data: { pan: pan},
    });
}
```

Look the Angular Material doc to create the dialogComponent

Comment: i want to add it in an other component not as a dialog.ts ! how to add it? for example in users.component.ts ? i mean in the same file containing the script of the list of users.